# Thunderbird won't ask for NNTP password—how to fix?

Tags: passwords, thunderbird

Have not been on Usenet for ages.  Don't remember deleting profile, but it was gone when I launched Thunderbird.  Deleted the ~/Library/Thunderbird dir to force creating a new one.

Added the news account (eternal-september) and tried to subscribe.  Only shows the unauthenticated groups; won't ask for a password to find others.  Won't allow posting in those groups either.

Have had this issue before but do not know the cause.  Several pages tell me to erase it from the "Saved Passwords" but there is nothing there (can't be, since it has never asked for username or password to put in there!)

One page said to delete a file names signons.txt but no such file exists.

Comment: This weird problem persisted through several reboots and launchings of Thunderbird, then it went back to working normally.